# What is the -- in CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Im not the best at CSS and came across a piece of code that kind of confuses me.

```css
.grid-product__title.grid-product__title--body:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I had a look at MDN and it usual declares a reusable property, like a variable?

But what does it mean if it is in the selector? Is it maybe a parent selector of `.grid-product__title.grid-product__title` and gives it an underline when the parent body is selected or something? Im highly confused

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not special to CSS, it's just part of the [BEM (Block, Element, Modifier) naming methodology](http://getbem.com/naming/) where you're supposed to name your selectors as `BLOCK__ELEMENT--MODIFIER`, so

- `grid-product` is the block
- `title` is the element
- `body` is the modifier (though in all honesty that's maybe a bit of an adapted "modifier").